# Why is the calibration signal's amplitude of my oscilloscope 10 times higher than stated?

Tags: oscilloscope, probe, calibration, amplitude

I'm trying to calibrate my HAMEG HM507 oscilloscope.

The manual says that the calibration signal is 0.2Vpp. With the attentuation of the probe set to x10, volts/division set to 5mV/cm, time/division set to 0.2ms/cm, I should see a square wave with a 4cm amplitude.

But that's not the case. I have to set volts/div. to 50mV in order to see the waveform correctly, because the amplitude is actually 10 times bigger! And indeed, when reading the calibration signal with attentuation set to X1, the scope shows a square wave with an amplitude of 2 volts.

But both the manual and the label on the scope say that the amplitude of the signal is 0.2Vpp. And in the settings I can only set the frequency of the test signal.

Is this an error in the manual? Is there some unknown zoom function that stretches the y-axis? (That can't be, because the x-magnification also adjusts the time/div. indicator). Maybe it's a function that multiplies the signal by 10 to adjust to the attentuation?

Comment: Run a wire from the Cal point to the BNC center pin. Get any probe error out of the picture.

Comment: It may be that your volts per division setting is already factoring in the probe attenuation, in which case the signal would be 40 divisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not find what type of probes were delivered with your scope, but I did find the [manual](http://web.itu.edu.tr/ozayan/ele311/HM507.pdf).

With 0.2 V<sub>PP</sub>, it makes sense that you want a "final" scale of 50 mV/cm. 200 mV<sub>PP</sub> / 50 mV/cm gives you the final 4 cm<sub>PP</sub>.

Since you actually get the correct signal with the correct setting using your probe in the X10 mode, I can only assume that the oscilloscope is also configured in this mode:

[image]

As you can see, each input has an x1/x10 setting, which you can toggle by holding the corresponding button.

> Probe  factor  selection  is  performed  by  pressing  and
>   holding  the  pushbutton.  This  selects  the  indicated
>   deflection  coefficient  of  channel  I  displayed  in  the
>   readout,  between  1:1  and  10:1.  In  condition  10:1,  the
>   probe  factor  is  thus  indicated  by  a  probe  symbol
>   displayed  by  the  readout  in  front  of  the  channel
>   information (e.g. ”probe symbol”, Y1...).